# Can I run vue file independent like html?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

If we want to run html then we can use usual browsers like Chrome.

Is there a tool for vue files like the browsers for html?

Comment: Same. Browsers.

Comment: But when i open it simply by the browsers, it shows just source codes. if it is html file then it shows not just tag source codes

Comment: unlike html files, vue source code files (.vue) needs to be compiled by you first. once you have compiled it, you can open the files in your deployment folder (.dist, .res or whatever is configured in npm).

Comment: mmm ok then we can't run vue file independent maybe. thx for explaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [vue cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html).

If you have npm or yarn installed you can run vue easily in your browser.

```
npm run serve
# OR
yarn serve
```

(To use the CLI, the project must also have been created with the CLI)

Comment: But then we need to run the command, i meant we can open the html files through just write its address on address bar, like that if there is a tool like that, the program that we can simply open the vue file